# Faceting but only showing a subset in each facet in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886057/limiting-the-number-of-categories-on-facets-in-a-facet-plot), but I cannot make that answer work for my plot.

I am making a timeline using `geom_linerange` for a group of names (`1:20`), each of which is associated with a sponsor (`B:E`). I want to "facet" the graph so the names/timelines are grouped by sponsor. So far I can get a combined plot if I create a "Combo" factor, which contains the sponsor+name. However, if I try to facet, then each sponsor gets *all* the names.

Here is my (a modified subset) of my data set (I am using `lubridate` for the dates...):

```
structure(list(Sponsor = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("B", 
"C", "D", "E"), class = "factor"), Last = structure(1:20, .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"), class = "factor"), 
Grant = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 
0, 1, 1, 0), Start = structure(c(844128000, 904003200, 1001289600, 
1314835200, 1064188800, 1107561600, 1138838400, 1264896000, 
1222819200, 1042502400, 1343779200, 904521600, 950832000, 
1009929600, 1081209600, 1171929600, 821664000, 865209600, 
979603200, 1209600000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
End = structure(c(929232000, 946684800, 1088035200, NA, 1109721600, 
1324512000, 1232496000, NA, NA, 1101859200, 1388448000, 993859200, 
1006819200, 1103500800, 1139529600, 1235952000, 919036800, 
1030665600, 1047254400, 1272585600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Combo = c("B_1", "B_2", "B_3", 
"B_4", "B_5", "B_6", "B_7", "B_8", "C_9", "C_10", "C_11", 
"D_12", "D_13", "D_14", "D_15", "D_16", "E_17", "E_18", "E_19", 
"E_20")), .Names = c("Sponsor", "Last", "Grant", "Start", 
"End", "Combo"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the command to generate the non-faceted plot which groups things in order, but not subdivided:

```
library(ggplot2)
require(lubridate)

YearLine = ymd(19960101) + years(seq(0,18))

ggplot(testdat,aes(Combo, Start, ymin=Start,ymax=End,color=as.factor(Grant),xticks)) + xlab("Sponsor") + geom_linerange(size=4,alpha=.7) + geom_point(size=4,shape=18) + coord_flip()  + scale_colour_brewer(palette="Spectral") + scale_x_discrete(labels=testdat$Sponsor) + geom_hline(yintercept = as.numeric(YearLine),alpha=0.6,col="indianred1",linetype="dotted")  + annotate("text", x = testdat$Combo, y = testdat$Start, label = testdat$Last, hjust=0,size=2.5)
```

And here is the plot that this generates. This is sort of what I want (in that it is not redundant) but I would like it subdivided by Sponsor:

[image: Plot example]

If I add `+ facet_grid(Sponsor ~ .,scale="free_x",space="free_x")` (or `free_y`), then it facets the panels by Sponsor as I was hoping, but I still get all the names listed, even if they are not relevant to that "Sponsor" B through E:

[image: Faceted attempt]

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you had was using `annotate` where you needed to use `geom_text`:

```
ggplot(testdat,aes(Combo, Start, ymin=Start,ymax=End,color=as.factor(Grant),xticks)) + 
  xlab("Sponsor") + geom_linerange(size=4,alpha=.7) + geom_point(size=4,shape=18) + coord_flip()  + 
  scale_colour_brewer(palette="Spectral") + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels=testdat$Sponsor) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = as.numeric(YearLine),alpha=0.6,col="indianred1",linetype="dotted")  + 
  geom_text(aes(x=Combo, y=Start, label = testdat$Last), colour="black") +
  facet_grid(Sponsor ~ .,scale="free_x",space="free_x")
```

`annotate` doesn't really follow the existing aesthetic mappings you've defined for the rest of the plot, which is why it wasn't affected by your faceting.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried with/without the `annotate` line in there... but in your plot, I still see *all* the names on the y-axis even for the Sponsors where there are no names. For example in panel E at the bottom, I don't want it to show lines for 1-16 on the y (actually x-flipped) axis... I am hoping that the `scale` parameter will remove those lines. I'll try some more variations without `annotate` in there...